# How to drop index column using panda while writing?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(['AA ', 'BB ', '','DD', 'EE',''],df.columns))
```

I used the above code in my script that's why I have to set `index=True`

```
df.to_excel(arg,index=True)
```

But now I want to drop my `index column`
What can I Do?

I Tried : `df.reset_index(inplace=True)  data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)   df.drop()` But no one is worked..!

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of what your dataframe looks like now (with the index column) and what you would want it to look like (without the index column)? reset_index with drop=True and inplace=True?

Answer (score 1):

To drop the index column, use this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting index to 'False' while exporting to excel ?

```py
df.to_excel(arg,index=False)
```

Comment: It gives an error..!

Comment: It gives an error because I am using pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(['AA ', 'BB ', '','DD', 'EE',''],df.columns))